# PostgreSQL 14 blocked

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, vacuum, postgresql-14, autovacuum

I have a fairly serious problem with PostgreSQL, it happens at intervals of a few days that some tables on my PostgreSQL instance crash, or rather this is my feeling.

Linked queries are very slow.

That said I immediately run a `VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE [tablename]` and I see that the tables I use in the query have several dead rows.

After this I start a `VACUUM FULL [tablename]` and after it has completed, according to the output the issues are resolved and the whole database continues to work perfectly.

Do you have any advice or solution on this?

Moreover, isn't the `AUTOVACUUM` command also a standard on Linuux that should do this work? Could it be that it doesn't work properly, and then starting it by hand (`VACUUM FULL...`) then unlocks / repairs the issues?

For example if i run VACUUM verbose analyze rigamovimentodettagliotaglia:
this is the result

> INFO:  vacuuming "public.rigamovimentodettagliotaglia"
> INFO:  table "rigamovimentodettagliotaglia": index scan bypassed: 10 pages from table (0.04% of total) have 81 dead item identifiers
> INFO:  table "rigamovimentodettagliotaglia": found 0 removable, 2910 nonremovable row versions in 41 out of 28104 pages
> DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 599479
> Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 28063 frozen pages.
> CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
> INFO:  analyzing "public.rigamovimentodettagliotaglia"
> INFO:  "rigamovimentodettagliotaglia": scanned 28104 of 28104 pages, containing 2506260 live rows and 81 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 2506260 estimated total rows
> VACUUM

Now there are 81 dead rows, tomorrow for example there will be 181 and etc etc.
When this reaches 4000 or more the query with join with this table is very slow.

I add here a EXPLAIN ANALYZE query result:
[image]

Comment: What is a "linked query"?

Comment: You need to figure out what the issue is. Show the output of an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of a slow query.

Comment: I changed the question by adding an analyze table

Comment: I add image with result of explain analyze, thanks jjanes

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Is the plan you show from when it was being "very slow"?

Comment: Excuse me in what sense since it was very slow, do you want to know when it began to give me problems?